# What's the best way to write a disk frame to CSV?

Tags: r, data.table, fwrite, fread, disk.frame

I'm looking through the [docs and](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/disk.frame/disk.frame.pdf) I don't see a function for writing to CSV.

It appears there's a function for writing the disk frame, but it's unclear what format it gets stored in

> write_disk.frame
>
> Write a data.frame/disk.frame to a disk.frame location. If df is a data.frame then using the as.disk.framefunction is recommended for most cases

Can I use `fwrite` or `write_csv` with a disk frame?

Comment: why don't you try it, and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see. I might add the write to csv functionality as I see this request quite often.

The best way to keep track though is to submit an issue on github https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/issues I have done that this time see https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/issues/311

If you want to write each chunk to a separate CSV just do

```
df %>%
  cimap(function(id, chunk) {
    data.table::fwrite(chunk, file.path("some/path/", paste0(id, ".csv"))
    NULL # return null since you don't need to return anything
  }, lazy=FALSE)
```

E.g.

```
library(disk.frame)

a = as.disk.frame(nycflights13::flights)

cimap(a, function(chunk, id) {
  data.table::fwrite(chunk, file.path(tempdir(), paste0(id, ".csv")))
  NULL
}, lazy=FALSE)


dir(tempdir())
```

If you wish to write to one file just modify to write to one file via `append=TRUE`, but make sure you turn off multiple workers!

```
setup_disk.frame(workers = 1) # only one worker
cmap(a, function(chunk) {
  data.table::fwrite(chunk, file.path(tempdir(), "one_file.csv"), append = TRUE)
  NULL
}, lazy=FALSE)
setup_disk.frame() # turn multi worker back on 


dir(tempdir())
```